# Nested struct with dynamic size in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, dynamic, struct, nested

I am trying to print data in showValues(mainStruct*) but I am unable to do so..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

typedef struct
{
  uint32_t someNumber;    
}subStruct;

typedef struct{
    uint32_t sizeofSubStruct;
    subStruct subStructArray[1];
}mainStruct;
```

This function construct the mainStruct and fill it with some values

```
mainStruct* constructMainStruct()
{
    mainStruct* msPtr;
    msPtr = (mainStruct*)malloc(sizeof(mainStruct)*10);
    msPtr->sizeofSubStruct = 10;

    subStruct* ssPtr = msPtr->subStructArray;
    for(uint32_t i=0; i < msPtr->sizeofSubStruct; i++)
    {
        ssPtr->someNumber = i+10;
        ssPtr++;       
    }             
    return msPtr;
}
```

Following function does not print anything

```
void showValues(mainStruct* msPtr)
{
    subStruct* ssPtr = msPtr->subStructArray;
    for(uint32_t i=0; i < msPtr->sizeofSubStruct; i++)
    {   
     std::cout << " - " + ssPtr->someNumber <<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Main function

```
int main()
{
    //contructing mainStruct with some values
    mainStruct* msPtr = constructMainStruct();

    //trying to print values which has been created in above step
    showValues(msPtr);
}
```

Comment: Flexible array member is in C, this question has C++ tags. C++ does not have flexible arrays. You should use `std::vector` or `std::array` depending on the requirements.

Comment: Why is `malloc` used? Why not `new? `

Comment: Why using raw pointers and raw arrays at all? Just use container classes like `std::vector` and `std::array`.

Comment: In C++, the flexible array member idiom is undefined behavior.

Comment: No! unfortunitely i cannot use vector or array, It should be as it is.
Regarding flexible array, since it is c++ i have to give a size [1] as it is mentioned in the code.

Comment: Please explain: why `subStruct subStructArray[1];` has size 1? Isn't it the same as `subStruct subStruct_var;`? Or why not `subStruct* subStruct_array;`?

Comment: I am talking about a production code which is written back in 80s and cannot be changed and interfaces are defined as those structs.

Comment: @Ali _"I am talking about a production code which is written back in 80s"_ Good luck with such code in production. I'd seriously consider to take the efforts and refactor that shite.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ  Yep, sure :)

Comment: `constructMainStruct` is incorrect. It doesn't construct the array of `subStruct` correctly. It is mixing pointers of `mainStruct` and `subStruct`. It's creating 10 `mainStruct`'s and then iterating as if 10 `subStructs` were created. This is just plain wrong. Nothing to do, but throw it away and rewrite it correctly.

Comment: `showValues` just displays the value of `ssPtr->someNumber` - repeatably the same value. `ssPtr` is never changed to point at something else.

Comment: Consider replacing the print statements with the C equivalent and proceeding in C with a C compiler.

Comment: Missed the C++ tag, but that makes other part of the code somewhat curious... For example, why use `typedef` to define type-aliases for the structures? Class and structure names are also type-names, so e.g. `struct subStruct { ... };` is enough to define a "type" `subStruct`.

Comment: In C++, to do the flexible array member, used `typedef struct{ uint32_t sizeofSubStruct; subStruct subStructArray[1024]; } mainStruct;` and then REDUCE 1024 to the least needed value.  That will be non-UB (and also be okay for C code too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the working code for showValues

```
void showValues(mainStruct* msPtr)
{
    subStruct* ssPtr = msPtr->subStructArray;
    for(uint32_t i=0; i < msPtr->sizeofSubStruct; i++)
    {   
     std::cout << (ssPtr+i)->someNumber <<std::endl;
    }
}
```

and complete program code is as below:

```
#include <iostream>

typedef struct
{
  uint32_t someNumber;    
}subStruct;

typedef struct{
    uint32_t sizeofSubStruct;
    subStruct subStructArray[1];
}mainStruct;

mainStruct* constructMainStruct()
{
    mainStruct* msPtr;
    msPtr = (mainStruct*)malloc(sizeof(mainStruct)*10);
    msPtr->sizeofSubStruct = 10;

    subStruct* ssPtr = msPtr->subStructArray;
    for(uint32_t i=0; i < msPtr->sizeofSubStruct; i++)
    {
        ssPtr->someNumber = i+10;
        ssPtr++;       
    }             
    return msPtr;
}
void showValues(mainStruct* msPtr)
{
    subStruct* ssPtr = msPtr->subStructArray;
    for(uint32_t i=0; i < msPtr->sizeofSubStruct; i++)
    {   
     std::cout << (ssPtr+i)->someNumber <<std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    //contructing mainStruct with some values
    mainStruct* msPtr = constructMainStruct();

    //trying to print values which has been created in above step
    showValues(msPtr);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your printing problem (which is by no means the only issue) is in the line:

```
for(uint32_t i=0; i > msPtr->sizeofSubStruct; i++)
```

You initialize i to 0 but use a test of "i > msPtr->sizeofSubStruct;", it should be less-than rather than greater-than.

Other problems are with your allocation size, it should be sizeof(mainStruct)+sizeof(subStruct)*9, it's not a huge problem with the subStruct you have right now but as soon as subStruct becomes something complicated it would be.

Comment: Size should be `offsetof(mainStruct, subStructArray) + sizeof(subStruct)*10`. But it's probably all UB anyway.

Comment: Yes! you are right regarding "i > msPtr->..", it was typo while writing sample code here. Despite correcting this, it does not print.

Comment: @Ali I think it should, but in any case to find out what's going on you need to use a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Besides what @SoronelHaetir has already noticed, the function `showValues` is not incrementing the `subStruct` pointer.

The code should look like this;

```
void showValues(mainStruct* msPtr)
{
    subStruct* ssPtr = msPtr->subStructArray;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < msPtr->sizeofSubStruct; i++)
    {
        std::cout << " - " + ssPtr->someNumber << std::endl;
        ++ssPtr;
    }
}
```